# Method for changing any field of the class

Tags: c#, .net, oop, setter

I have a method Set, and I want to pass name of the field and new value so it could change any field.
Like:

```
Person a = new Person("Marco", 5);
a.Set("age", 6);
```

My realization doesn't work, how to fix it?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Project
{
    public class Person
    {
        string name;
        int age;

        public Person(string name1, int age1)
        {
            name = name1;
            age = age1;
        }
        public void Set(string field_name, string new_value)
        {
            Type obj = typeof(Person);
            obj.GetProperty(field_name).SetValue(null, new_value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: replace null with this and GetProperty with GetField, also field should be public (or you should right binding flags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `null` with `this` to set the value of a property of the current instance of `Person`:

```
obj.GetProperty(field_name).SetValue(this, new_value);
```

But since you have non-public *fields*, you should use `GetField` with some binding flags:

```
obj.GetField(field_name, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
    .SetValue(this, new_value);
```

You probably also want a method to *get* the values and change the type of `new_value` to `object`.

Also note that setting values like this, instead of using strongly typed properties, is both slower and prone to errors. Depending on your requirements, you may want to consider using a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

Comment: Gives an error `Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: @Aska: See my edit.